# Somehow the below code is working but i wanted this with $ajax instead of $.postmethod

Tags: jquery, validation

1. Trying to achieve this with ajax but when I use to submit page refreshes normally
2. what is use of ajax then

   ```
   submitHandler:function(form){
    $.ajax({
         url: form.action,
         type: form.method,
         data: form.serialize(),           
         beforeSend: function() {
           $('#loading').show();                           
         },
         complete: function(){                                    
           $('#loading').hide();           
         },
         success: function(data)
         {             
           console.log(data);
         }

       });
       $(form).submit();
     }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently achived my work with below **$.POST** method and working good and efficently.

```
submitHandler:function(form){
 $.post('userinsertcheck.php',
  $("#registration_form").serialize(),
   function(){
    $("#dialogtext").html("Account Created Successfully");
     $("#dialog").dialog({
      buttons: {            
       "OK": function () {
         $(this).dialog("close");                       
         }
       }
      });
     $("#dialog").dialog("open");                   
   });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX allows us to post and get data *asynchronously* - removing the need for page refreshes. If you don't want your page to refresh, you'll need to call `preventDefault()` on the submit event to override the browser's default form submission.

Your page here is refreshing because you're automatically and somewhat unnecessarily triggering `$(form).submit()` and have no checks in place to prevent the default browser behaviour.

Comment: `preventDefault()` is actually written with event in function whereas `submitHandler:function(form){` is written then where i should write it.